Get MobileFrontend to use a different version of HtmlFormatter
(Using MediaWiki 1.39.8) As there is a compatibility issue with another extension, I want the MobileFrontend extension to use a different version of HtmlFormatter (directory: vendor/wikimedia/html-formatter and file: vendor/wikimedia/html-formatter/src/HtmlFormatter.php)
I can see in extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/MobileFormatter.php these lines:
use HtmlFormatter\HtmlFormatter;
use MobileFrontend\Transforms\IMobileTransform;

class MobileFormatter extends HtmlFormatter

What I did was

Add a copy of the directory vendor/wikimedia/html-formatter as vendor/wikimedia/html-formatterold containing the appropriate HtmlFormatter.php for MobileFrontend renamed as HtmlFormatterOld.php.
Add a copy of the file vendor/wikimedia/html-formatter/src/HtmlFormatter.php as vendor/wikimedia/html-formatter/src/HtmlFormatterOld.php (containing the appropriate HtmlFormatter.php for MobileFrontend).
I have adapted the code in extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/MobileFormatter.php as

use HtmlFormatterOld\HtmlFormatterOld;
use MobileFrontend\Transforms\IMobileTransform;

class MobileFormatter extends HtmlFormatter

And also tried with renaming the class line accordingly with the -Old suffix in various permutations (class MobileFormatter extends HtmlFormatter). But I keep getting errors, is there something else that I should do?
[Zv0PNh1w9rSjwI8eTr_25wADSRE] /index.php?title=Main_Page&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile Error: Class "HtmlFormatter" not found

Backtrace:

from ..extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/MobileFormatter.php(9)
#0 ..includes/AutoLoader.php(244): require()
#1 ..extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/ExtMobileFrontend.php(106): AutoLoader::autoload(string)
#2 ..extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/ExtMobileFrontend.php(67): ExtMobileFrontend::domParseMobile(OutputPage, string)
#3 ..extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/MobileFrontendHooks.php(314): ExtMobileFrontend::domParseWithContentProvider(MobileFrontend\ContentProviders\DefaultContentProvider, OutputPage, boolean)
#4 ..includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(338): MobileFrontendHooks::onOutputPageBeforeHTML(OutputPage, string)
#5 ..includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(137): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->callLegacyHook(string, array, array, array)
#6 ..includes/HookContainer/HookRunner.php(2686): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->run(string, array)
#7 ..includes/OutputPage.php(2221): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookRunner->onOutputPageBeforeHTML(OutputPage, string)
#8 ..includes/OutputPage.php(2233): OutputPage->addParserOutputText(ParserOutput, array)
#9 ..includes/page/Article.php(819): OutputPage->addParserOutput(ParserOutput, array)
#10 ..includes/page/Article.php(721): Article->doOutputFromRenderStatus(MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionStoreCacheRecord, Status, OutputPage, array)
#11 ..includes/page/Article.php(528): Article->generateContentOutput(User, ParserOptions, integer, OutputPage, array)
#12 ..includes/actions/ViewAction.php(78): Article->view()
#13 ..includes/MediaWiki.php(542): ViewAction->show()
#14 ..includes/MediaWiki.php(322): MediaWiki->performAction(Article, Title)
#15 ..includes/MediaWiki.php(904): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#16 ..includes/MediaWiki.php(562): MediaWiki->main()
#17 ..index.php(50): MediaWiki->run()
#18 ..index.php(46): wfIndexMain()

